# glossaries outputs only one entry for custom list

Tags: glossaries

I want to use two glossaries, one for acronyms and one for a list of symbols. In the preamble I load the glossaries package with acronym and xindy options: `\usepackage[nomain,acronym,xindy,toc]{glossaries}`, and make the new glossary `\newglossary[nlg]{notation}{not}{ntn}{Notation}`.

My acronyms and symbols are all defined in a dedicated file, loaded using `\loadglsentries{Glossaire}`. References are collected (by xindy) using `makeglossaries -d build main` (the `-d` option because I compile into a sub-directory using `pdflatex -output-directory=build`).

In my document I use the `\gls` command, in the MWE I use `\glsaddall` with the same result: only first symbol is printed in the notation glossary.

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside]{report}
\usepackage[nomain,acronym,xindy,toc]{glossaries}
  \newglossary[nlg]{notation}{not}{ntn}{Notation}
  \loadglsentries{Glossaire}
  \makeglossaries

\begin{document}
  \glsaddall
  \printglossary[type=\acronymtype , title={Liste des acronymes}, toctitle={Liste des acronymes}]
  \printglossary[type=notation,title={Liste des symboles}, toctitle={Liste des symboles}]

\end{document}
```

And the definitions:

```
\newacronym{ac1}{AC1}{not an ACronym, but still first one}
\newacronym{ac2}{AC2}{not an ACronym, second one}

\newglossaryentry{indice r}{
  type=notation,
  name={indice ${}_r$},
  symbol={\ensuremath{a_r}},
  description={L'indice ${}_r$ blabla},
  sort={alpha}%
}
\newglossaryentry{intervalle}{
  type=notation,
  name={intervalle $[{a}{b}]$},
  symbol={\ensuremath{[{a}{b}]}},
  description={blabla $a$ and $b$},
  sort={alpha}%
}
```

Beside the `providecommand`s, the not file has only one entry too:

```
\begin{theglossary}\glossaryheader
\glsgroupheading{A}\relax\glsresetentrylist
\glossentry{indice r}{\glossaryentrynumbers{\relax 
\glsXpageXglsnumberformat{}{1}}}%
\end{theglossary}\glossarypostamble
```

Any ideas or obvious stuff I missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `xindy` and use the same `sort` key for both entries. Hence, they are treated as a single entry and only one ends up in the final glossary. See the large red box on page 76 of the package manual. To avoid this, give them distinct `sort` keys (or use a different method to sort and produce the glossary).

For example:

```
\begin{filecontents}{a.tex}
  \newacronym{ac1}{AC1}{not an ACronym, but still first one}
  \newacronym{ac2}{AC2}{not an ACronym, second one}

  \newglossaryentry{indice r}{
    type=notation,
    name={indice ${}_r$},
    symbol={\ensuremath{a_r}},
    description={L'indice ${}_r$ blabla},
    sort={alpha1}%
  }
  \newglossaryentry{intervalle}{
    type=notation,
    name={intervalle $[{a}{b}]$},
    symbol={\ensuremath{[{a}{b}]}},
    description={blabla $a$ and $b$},
    sort={alpha2}%
  }
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside]{report}
\usepackage[nomain,acronym,xindy,toc]{glossaries}
\newglossary[nlg]{notation}{not}{ntn}{Notation}
\loadglsentries{a}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
  \glsaddall
  \printglossary[type=\acronymtype, title={Liste des acronymes}, toctitle={Liste des acronymes}]
  \printglossary[type=notation,title={Liste des symboles}, toctitle={Liste des symboles}]

\end{document}
```

[image: double entry]